# Set default landing page for a particular profile

Tags: administration, setup, user-profile

We are trying to set the landing page for a particular profile, that profile has access to only 2 apps and both the apps do not have a default landing page set. We also do not have org level landing page set but still when we login with a user of that profile it takes us to "Dashboard' tab. We have a default app for this profile and have set 'Home' page as default for this profile from within the App Builder.
Strangely, once logged in and if we switch to other App and then comes back to first App then it defaults to the Home page. How can we set Home page as default landing page when we login?
FYI the default App is a managed app.

Answer (score 1):

click the + on the end of the tabs >  customize my tab > select app > any tab you move up becomes default landing page